# Change name of directories and included file

Tags: bash, files, replace

In a directory I have several sub-directories named as follow (the [1-9] means going from 1 to 9):

```
AA_BB_CC_river[1-9]
```

Each sub-directories contains a file (ascii) having exactly the same name as the directory. I did a mistake in the naming of several sub-directories (and their enclosed files):

```
AA_BB_CC_rier[1-9]
```

How can I replace `rier` by `river` in the subdirectory and the enclosed file naming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow external programs you can use `find` and `rename`:

```
find . -type f -name '*_rier*' -exec rename 's/rier/river/g' {} \+
find . -type d -name '*_rier*' -exec rename 's/rier/river/g' {} \+
```

If you don't want to use external tools you can use

```
# rename directories
for f in *rier*; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f/rier/river}"
done

# rename files
for f in */*rier*; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f/rier/river}"
done
```

This first renames the directories and then the files.

Comment: The second option works. But the first one not, (I am curious) therefore, I would like to know if you have an idea about why the first option is not working?

Comment: @steve It has to be done in two steps. Otherwise the path is wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: shouldn't that be `for f in *rier*/ ; do ...` and `for f in */*rier* ; do`?  or if you swap the order so the files are renamed before the dirs `for f in *rier*/*rier* ; do ...`?  that'll eliminate attempts to rename files that don't need to be renamed.

Comment: @cas Sure `for f in *` will act on *all* files and directories, not only the ones containing “rier”. So `*rier*` would be more precise but longer. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(find . -depth -name '*rier*'); do 
  mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/rier/river/');
done
```

Comment: It does change the name of the directories, but not the name of the enclosed file and produce the error `mv: cannot move DIRECTORY_NAME/FILE_NAME.txt to NEW_DIRECTORY_NAME/NEW_FILE_NAME.txt: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop:

```
for d in AA_BB_CC_rier*; do
  [ -d "$d" ] && \
    mv -v -- "$d/$d" "$d/${d/rier/river}" && \
    mv -v -- "$d" "${d/rier/river}"
done
```

---

- `for` loops trough all items starting with `AA_BB_CC_rier`.
- `[ -d "$d" ]` checks if it's a directory.
- `mv` renames the file in the directory.
- The second call of `mv` renames the directory itself.